# Problem with fixed row and scroll lock - Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a page with some content at the top, and a 'table' type area just below. When the user scrolls past the top part, I want the row that serves as table header to fix at the top of the window and the rest of the content to scroll. I am using bootstrap 4.
The javascript (jQuery) here below allows me to do this, but when I scroll, the proportions of the header row change completely: either too small or too big:

```
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
  var $el = $('.header-fix');
  var isPositionFixed = ($el.css('position') == 'fixed');
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 && !isPositionFixed) {
    $el.css({
      'position': 'fixed', 
      'top': '0px',
      /*'width': '100%' */
    });

  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200 && isPositionFixed) {
    $el.css({
      'position': 'static',
      'top': '0px'
    });

  }
});
```

(See broken example here: https://codepen.io/alexm588/pen/RqWgdO )

The problem I think I have is that when the row gets the 'fixed' attribute to stay at the top of the window, the bootstrap logic doesn't work anymore. If I put a width: 100%, then it extends far outside of the container, if I don't specify anything it doesn't align to the grid. 
Anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks! 
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for jQuery at all. This can already be achieved with bootstrap functions.

Just apply the CSS class 'sticky-top' to the div you want to stay on top. Have a look at the updated codepen.

```
<div class="row header-fix sticky-top">
```

[Stick to the top codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eQpGpX?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks, how did I miss this -_- sorry!